# MVVM передача свойства RadListBox.SelectedItems как параметр команды

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть CheckBox (самый верхний).

Есть RadListBox который заполняется CheckBox через привязку к коллекции (это работает).

```
<telerik:RadListBox
    MaxHeight="250"
    Background="Transparent"
    telerik:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior.SelectedItemsSource="{Binding SelectedScripts}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Scripts}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScript,
                           Mode=TwoWay,
                           ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    Command="{Binding SelectItems}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadListBox}},Path=SelectedItems}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <telerik:RadListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadListBoxItem">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadListBoxItem}, 
                                      Path=IsSelected}"
                                  Content="{Binding Title}"
                                  Height="25" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

К верхнему CheckBox я прописал команду которая отмечает/снимает выделение у всех нижних CheckBox'сов (она работает).

Что я хочу ещё сделать: 1)если один из нижних CheckBox'сов не был отмечен тогда "снимается" верхний CheckBox.
2) если верхний CheckBox не был отмечен, но в ручную проставлены нижние CheckBox'сы, верхний отмечается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: А как вы пробовали? Выглядит не сложно, бежим в цикле по всем, проверяем что нужно и решаем надо поставить или снять верхний

Comment: Да, удалось. На днях выложу код.